# Add/Update realmObject in RealmList

Tags: realm, realm-list

I have a realmList, say studentsList within a realmObject, say class. I want to request a list of students for a given class and update the same within studentList.
Server returned studentList may contain old as well as new students. So I want my realmList to update information for old students along with addition of new students if any.

What I did is ,

1. Initiated a loop with size == serverReturnedStudentList.size()
2. Created student within loop and added in realm (using realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(student))
3. Received managed student object from step 2.
4. Fetch student List for class X and checked if the studentList contains that managedObject or not.
5. If not, added student to studentList else did nothing.

It is working as expected but I know this is not the right approach. If I skip that "contains" check (@step4) and directly add managed object to realmList,  multiple entries starts displaying in realmList.

What would be the best approach to handle this scenario?

Another issue is, I have 'n' number of class and 'x' sections under each class. I am making n.x requests in parallel and when I try to start asyncExecutions n.x times, I got pool size limit exception ( which is obvious) and I can't run this on UI thread as my UI becomes unresponsive for 3-5 seconds(while the loop for each studentList is getting executed with executeTransaction for each student)

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance. Cheers!

Comment: `multiple entries starts displaying in realmList. What would be the best approach to handle this scenario?` do you have a `@PrimaryKey`?

Comment: Also, don't execute a transaction for each student, I'm not sure why you're doing that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I do have a primary key for each student object and to clarify further, there is only a single object for student say x, but multiple entries are there for studentX in studentList if I skip studentList.contains(studentX) step before adding studentX to studentList.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Another option is to iterate through studentList of just created students(realmObjects) inside a realmTransaction first to add object to realm to get managed object and then to check if that managed object is already there in realmStudentList. If not, then adding that managed object to realmList. My concern is when to add realmObject(managedStudent) to realmList(realmStudentList) and when to just update the old realmObject(managedStudent).

Comment: Consider adding code. I read Java better than English pseudocode. :P

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems ok to me. One thing you need to understand that **copyToRealmOrUpdate()** for updating your realmList wont't duplicate the data for the entries with same **Primary Key**.

Comment: Yes I understand the concept behind copyToRealmOrUpdate() and Yes I do have a primary key for each student object and to clarify further, there is only a single object for student say x, but multiple entries are there for studentX in studentList if I skip studentList.contains(studentX) step before adding studentX to studentList.

Comment: So let me get this correct - there is studentList which contains numerous entries for studentX and others. I now assume you are separating studentX from the list with studentList.contains(studentX) and trying to update the studentX. Is it?

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. What I want is to add student to studentList if not present in the list or just to update information of already present student in the list. If we have a student already present/attached to a studentList and I perform copyToRealmOrUpdate(unManagedStudent), information will be updated and nothing else needs to be done. but if such student wasn't there in the studentList, I still need to perform copyToRealmOrUpdate(unManagedStudent) along with one more step that is to add nowManagedStudent to realmList.